# Max length ignoring one character in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a Regex Which allows up to 6 decimals("." is the decimal separator)

```
/^\d*[.]?\d{0,6}$/
```

I also want to put max length condition so that user can only enter 12 digits and max length should exclude "." how do I do that with Regex.

Comment: Easy win: Create two regexps, one for the 12 check and the one you already have, both must match.

Comment: Good idea, but how would you do that? e.g `^[0-9\.]{13}$` is not good, as it allows multiple dots. @MartinWickman

Comment: Assuming you have a programming language: `if (regex1.match(input) && match(regex2.match(input)) { ...}`

Comment: Thanks all. I am using it in JQuery for input filter so I needed it in on regex to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead to check for either a number with a decimal place with up to 6 digits after it or a string of 12 digits) and then match up to 13 characters in total:

```
^(?=\d*\.\d{0,6}$|\d{1,12}$).{1,13}$
```

For this input, the 2nd and 5th values will match:

```
1234567890123
123456.789012
12345.6789012
1234567.890123
12345.67890
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vHdArC/3)

Comment: That worked like a charm thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick

Answer (score 1):

We could try using negative lookaheads:

```
^(?:(?!.*\.)(?!\d{13})|(?=.*\.)(?![0-9.]{14}))\d+(?:\.\d{1,6})?$
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
^(?:                        from the start of the string
    (?!.*\.)(?!\d{13})      assert that no more than 12 digits appear
                            (in the case of a number with NO decimal point)
    |                       or
    (?=.*\.)(?![0-9.]{14})) assert that no more than 13 digits/decimal point appears
                            (in the case of a number which HAS a decimal point)
    \d+                     then match one or more digits (whole number portion)
    (?:\.\d{1,6})?          followed by an optional decimal component (1 to 6 digits)
$                           end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;**

```
^(?!(?:\D*\d){13})\d*[.]?\d{0,6}$ 
^(?=(?:\D*\d){0,12}\D*$)\d*[.]?\d{0,6}$
```

You can use a simple positive lookahead approach: keep your pattern (if it works as you expect) and insert

```
(?=(?:\D*\d){0,x}\D*$)
```

right after `^` and change the `x` to the required amount of digits.

So, you may use

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){0,12}\D*$)\d*[.]?\d{0,6}$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?=(?:\D*\d){0,12}\D*$)` matches a location that is immediately followed with zero to 12 occurrences of any 0+ non-digit chars followed with one digit one and then having any 0+ non-digits to the end of the string.

**See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k4lpJK/1)**

Alternatively, disallow a string with more than 13 digits:

```
^(?!(?:\D*\d){13})\d*[.]?\d{0,6}$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?!(?:\D*\d){13})` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 13 occurrences of any 0+ non-digits followed with a single digit chars.

This is better than the positive lookahead approach when you need to allow an empty string.

**See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k4lpJK/2)**